# GDI-Handle Leak

Tags: c#, .net, gdi, memory-leaks

I got a problem with GDI-Handle´s. I understand that windows limit´s the amount of GDI-Handles per application at 10.000. Then the application crashes.

On my own system and several virtual machines the amount of GDI-Handles stays between 300 and 500... no matter what I do. On a customer project it is getting higher and higher till it reaches 10.000 after some days.

```
13.06.2013: 12:47 GDI-Handles 1550

13.06.2013: 12:59 GDI-Handles 1553

13.06.2013: 13:07 GDI-Handles 1557

13.06.2013: 13:55 GDI-Handles 1564

13.06.2013: 15:29 GDI-Handles 2193

13.06.2013: 16:47 GDI-Handles 2201

13.06.2013: 17:14 GDI-Handles 2201

13.06.2013: 17:21 GDI-Handles 2201

13.06.2013: 17:29 GDI-Handles 2263
```

Why is the behavior on another pc with the exactly same .NET application so different? Any idea how i can debug it without visual studio installed on the system?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about computer specifics if there is a leak there will always be a leak until fixed. Is there any difference in the build you are using?

Comment: It might not be your code that's leaking.  An OpenFileDialog is for example a good way to inject shell extensions into your process that can misbehave like that.  If you cannot repro this at all then you'll need to dismiss this as a "sick machine" problem.  A minidump could show foreign DLLs being injected into your program, but is not conclusive.

Comment: no, there isn´t any difference. i copied the build to my system and tested with it. but no leak at all. maybe I am doing something different than the user, bu I don´t think so... is there any way to log all GDI-Handles associated with this application? What type they are...from which assembly...maybe the method they where created in... ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. On the system I got the bug I ran the tool "GDIView". With this tool I was able to determine that the problem-causing object is a Bitmap. I found the Bitmap causing the trouble and fount out that I have to dispose IntPtr manually (no help from the GC there).

```
            ImageSource wpfBitmap = null;

            if (this.buttonImage != null)
            {

                IntPtr hBitmap = this.buttonImage.GetHbitmap();

                wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                   hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            }

            return wpfBitmap;
```

So I just added the "DeleteObject()" method and the leak was gone.

Comment: This isn't a real answer until you can explain why this didn't cause a problem on your own machine.

Comment: It did cause the problem on my own machine. Sayse was absolutly right. I just didn´t find the trigger of the problem in my first approach

Comment: Then you definitely need to update your question, it doesn't match the answer.